# root user can't delete file

Tags: macos, root, macports, rm, macos-mojave

I've enabled root user in my mac using the latest Mojave. I am trying to delete a folder with it but for some reason I get the error "Permission denied". I thought root could do anything on a unix system?

```
sh-3.2# whoami
root
sh-3.2# pwd
/opt/local/var/macports/home/Library
sh-3.2# ls -lhart
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  admin    96B Sep 24  2016 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  admin    96B Sep 24  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  admin    64B Oct 13 18:54 Preferences
sh-3.2# rm -rf Preferences/
rm: Preferences/: Operation not permitted
sh-3.2# whoami
root
sh-3.2#
```

Comment: No you can't. [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection)

Comment: SIP seems to protect system files. I'm trying to delete the macports installation directory.

Comment: The macports installation directory is certainly not owned by `root` nor is it stored under `Preferences`.

Comment: /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences

Comment: I don't think this is that folder, can you `pwd` please? Also, OS version?

Comment: /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library
sh-3.2# 

OS is in the gags, Mojave.

Comment: Off-topic here. This is not a programming question but rather suited to superuser.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, that SIP protects the whole `/opt/local/var/macports/home` folder, as assumed above. It is not necessary to deactivate SIP to remove the folder however.

[This answer about MacPorts folder removal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342090/sip-preventing-deletion-of-opt-local/349415#349415) indicates that removing the "macports" user that this folder is the "home" of would allow root to delete the folder, so

```
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete "/Users/macports"
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete "/Groups/macports"
```

should allow `sudo rm -rf /opt/local/var/macports/home/Preferences` to work as desired.

If you do not want to remove the "macports" user, follow these steps to delete these folders using the terminal in [Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201314):

- Shutdown your Mac
- Boot your Mac and press immediately CMD + R at startup to start in Recovery Mode (you can release the keys when the Apple-logo shows up)
- Open the Terminal app
- cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/opt (Your harddisk name maybe differ from "Macintosh HD")
- rm -Rf local